# No persister for Entity

Tags: nhibernate, fluent

I define a simple Bug Class:

```
using System;

namespace BugNS.Entities
{
    class Bug
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
        public virtual int BugNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and a simple mapper class:

```
using System;
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;
using BugNS.Entities;

namespace BugNS.Mappings
{
    class BugMap : ClassMap<Bug>
    {
        public BugMap()
        {
            Id(b => b.Id);
            Map(b => b.BugNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

and then just try to use it like:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl;
using BugNS.Entities;

namespace BugNS
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string DbFile = "bugs.db";

        static void Main()
        {
            var sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();
            using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
            {
                using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    Bug b = new Bug { BugNumber = 121212 };
                    session.SaveOrUpdate(b);
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
        }

        private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
        {
            return Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard
                    .UsingFile(DbFile))
                .Mappings(m =>
                    m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>())
                .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
                .BuildSessionFactory();
        }

        private static void BuildSchema(Configuration config)
        {
            // delete the existing db on each run
            if (File.Exists(DbFile))
                File.Delete(DbFile);

            // this NHibernate tool takes a configuration (with mapping info in)
            // and exports a database schema from it
            new SchemaExport(config)
              .Create(false, true);
        }
    }
}
```

and I got the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'NHibernate.MappingException' occurred
>   in NHibernate.dll
>
> Additional information: No persister
>   for: BugNS.Entities.Bug

I am sorry, but I just started learning Fluent and NHibernate from the docs. It would be great if someone knows the solution to this issue, as I already spend many hours in vain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Access level of the class needs to be **public** for Fluent to make use of it.

Try the following:

```
public class Bug
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual int BugNumber { get; set; }
}

public class BugMap : ClassMap<Bug>
{
    public BugMap()
    {
        Id(b => b.Id);
        Map(b => b.BugNumber);
    }
}
```

This is a gotcha for me as well when I started using Fluent.

One more thing that generally goes wrong is missing out `virtual` keyword, which is needed for NHibernate to make changes to those properties. Its nice that you made that part correct :)

Hope that helps.

Thanks

Comment: Many thanks, Visual Studio created by default private classes and no where its mentioned to create public classes. Such simple mistakes cost lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the Bug and BugMap classes public so that NHibernate/Fluent NHibernate can see them.